# How to write copy() method for Simple Class in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a class Person

```
class Person(val name: String, val height : Int, val weight: Int)
```

I want to write `copy()` method for my class that can work same as the copy method does with case classes(copy and update the attribute of the object)

I know `copy()` comes with case class but i am not using them so i want the same thing for my class

please guide me how can i do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just create a copy method which includes as parameters all the fields from the class definition, but which uses the existing values as default parameters, then create a new instance using all the parameters:

```
class Person(val name: String, val height : Int, val weight: Int) {

  def copy(newName: String = name, newHeight: Int = height, newWeight: Int = weight): Person = 
    new Person(newName, newHeight, newWeight)

  override def toString = s"Name: $name Height: $height Weight: $weight"
}

val person = new Person("bob", 183, 85)

val heavy_person = person.copy(newWeight = 120)

val different_person = person.copy(newName = "frank")

List(person, heavy_person, different_person) foreach {
  println(_)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using same names for parameters in `copy` method would make it similar to the `copy` method in case classes.

```
class Person(val name: String, val height: Int, val weight: Int) {
  def copy(
      name: String = this.name,
      height: Int = this.height,
      weight: Int = this.weight,
  ) = new Person(name, height, weight)
}
```

The `copy` method can be used as following.

```
val john = new Person("John", 89, 160)
val joe = john.copy(name = "Joe")
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer from 5 years ago?

Comment: The method parameters are named to be similar to the case class copy method.